# How do I convert this line of code to swift, Im trying to make a sprite follow a circular path

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uibezierpath, skaction

How do I convert this line of code to swift:

```
// circle path
    UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) cornerRadius:100];
    SKAction *followCircle = [SKAction followPath:circle.CGPath asOffset:YES orientToPath:NO duration:5.0];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let circle = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100), cornerRadius: 100)
let followCircle = SKAction.followPath(circle.CGPath, asOffset: true, orientToPath: false, duration: 5.0)
```

As you see the code is very similar, it's just a different syntax.

Have fun with Swift!